# NextJS не видит новые файлы в public

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, nextjs

Если добавить изображдения в `public`, после `build` и `start` проекта, то я не могу обратиться к файлам, пока не пересоберу проект. Как это решается?

Answer (score -1):

В Next.js статические файлы, такие как изображения, помещенные в папку public, должны быть доступными без необходимости пересборки проекта при запуске в режиме разработки. Однако, когда вы используете команды build и start для создания и запуска оптимизированной продакшн-версии вашего приложения, все файлы из public копируются в папку .next во время сборки. Это означает, что после сборки добавление новых файлов в папку public напрямую не отразится в уже собранном приложении, так как они не были включены в процесс сборки.

**Решения:**

- Пересборка проекта: Простейшее решение — пересобрать и перезапустить проект после добавления новых файлов в public. Это гарантирует, что новые файлы будут включены в сборку.
- Использование внешнего сервера для статических файлов: Если вам необходимо динамически добавлять новые статические файлы без пересборки, рассмотрите возможность размещения этих файлов на внешнем сервере статических файлов или CDN. Вы можете ссылаться на эти файлы в вашем приложении Next.js, используя полные URL-адреса.
- Разработка кастомного сервера: Если вы используете кастомный сервер с Next.js (например, Express.js), вы можете настроить маршрутизацию таким образом, чтобы обрабатывать запросы к новым статическим файлам в папке public или любой другой директории вне процесса сборки Next.js. Это может включать в себя настройку статического промежуточного обработчика для обслуживания этих файлов.
- Использование разработки в режиме Hot Reload: В режиме разработки (next dev) Next.js автоматически обнаруживает добавление новых файлов в папку public и делает их доступными без перезапуска сервера. Это полезно во время разработки, но не применимо к продакшн-среде.
- Избегайте изменений в public в продакшне: Если возможно, старайтесь не вносить изменения в содержимое папки public после сборки для продакшна. Лучше всего вносить все необходимые изменения до сборки и перезапуска.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)